# (Yet Another) UVa 3n+1 Help Question

Tags: java

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why this is returning "Wrong Answer."  I'd greatly appreciate any feedback.

Edit: I reposted the code, and this version finally fixed the "Runtime Error" by allowing for multiple spaces between the number pair. It now is saying "Wrong Answer" but as far as I can tell, I copied the given algorithm verbatim, so I'm at a loss.

Thanks.

[The Problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Main mine = new Main();
   mine.begin();
}

public void begin(){
    BufferedReader sys = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] pair;
    try{
        while((pair=sys.readLine().split(" +")).length==2){
            System.out.println(pair[0]+ " " +pair[1] + " " + getMax(Integer.parseInt(pair[0]),Integer.parseInt(pair[1])));
        }
    }catch(IOException ex){
        return;
    }
}

private String getMax(int a, int b){
    int maxcount,thiscount, num, n;

    for(maxcount = -1, num =Math.min(a, b); num <= Math.max(a, b); num++ ){
        for(n = num, thiscount = 1; n!=1; thiscount++){
            if(n%2==0)n=n/2;
            else n = 3*n +1;
        }
        if(thiscount>maxcount) maxcount = thiscount;
    }
    return String.valueOf(maxcount);
}
}
```

Comment: A Wall Of Code doesn't help here. Can you narrow the problem down?

Comment: It is telling me that the code compiled and ran fine, but it was unable to solve the problem. I really have no idea why it saying wrong answer, but that "alforithm" is located in the getMax, getCount methods.

Comment: Are you at least matching the sample output with the sample inputs?  You need to consider any corner cases that might apply to the problem and handle them all.

Comment: When things are so complex you can't figure them out, you certainly need test cases.  Write test cases for getCount() and getMax()

Comment: It compiles and runs for me, and gives the same answers as the sample data.

Comment: At first I had written it to take all the inputs and then give all the outputs, but that just never worked at all (Runtime errors). I looked at the given solution and their answer gave it back immediately so I switched the code around to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(num<4){
...
```

Is the input always limited to 4 lines?

Comment: For some reason whenever I don't limit it to a set number it gives "Runtime Error." I don't know why that happens since I can just keep on giving inputs and finally ending with an empty line (like the given solution) and it runs just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: There is something in their sample data that makes parseInt() blow up. Perhaps it is a line of spaces, or a line that begins with a space. I tired lots of variations but still got either the wrong answer or a runtime error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `line = line.trim();` before `if(line.length()==0){return;}` and catching NumberFormatException?

Comment: I updated it to just get the pair immediately, and now it is saying "Wrong Answer".= (better than Runtime Error at least). I can't locate what I am doing wrong and this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider how you parse the lines.  I believe the only lines that could have runtime errors in your code are the integer parsing ones.  You're assuming that each `i` and `j` are separated by a single space.  The question makes no mention of how much whitespace will be on a line.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to fix the runtime error problem, but now it is saying "wrong answer." Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a wrong answer, and your program works on the samples, then the problem is probably tied to the fact that you're using ints rather then longs.

For the 3n+1 problem, the intermediate values can grow to be larger then an int can handle (2,147,483,647), and it's a common way for judge data to be evil.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried using long in place of int and it is still returning that I got the wrong answer. I found a solution on the website (this is the very first problem and shouldn't be difficult after all). It looks like the solution just uses int and does the same thing as my code, but when I submitted his to make sure the site isn't bugged, it says "accepted." It is here http://acm.uva.es/p/data/p100.java.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing in UVA judge is:

1. Get the output exactly the same. No extra lines at the end.
2. Never throw exception just return or break with No output for Outside boundary parameters.
3. Output is case sensitive
4. Output parameters should maintain spaces as shown in the problem

Here is link at Stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632770/1060656